# What is the best ViewController to use for setting up a multi step Sign Up page?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, scrollview

What kind of UiViewController or what kind of setup should I use for creating a multi step Sign Up menu, with UITextFields and data validation before sliding to the next step?

I am currently thinking of using a UiViewController of with a UIScrollView that has multiple views on it. The problem with this approach is that I do not have an index path, therefore it will be hard to configure when my textfields should become first responders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableviewController will useful for form views

You can create a sections & cells for each type of input fields and images

Comment: got it. I actually tried that and UICollectionViewController, the problem is that is they all dequeue cells, and for some reason that gets very screwy on my textfields

Comment: Don’t reuse the cells. Design each cells separately in storyboard. This better way for design and debugging